# FFmpeg: Protocol not on whitelist 'file'!

Tags: c, ffmpeg, rtp

I want to read from an RTP stream, but when I specify "test.sdp" to `avformat_open_input()` I get this message:

```
[rtp @ 03928900] Protocol not on whitelist 'file'!
Failed: cannot open input.
avformat_open_input() fail: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Normally if I were using ffplay on the console, I would add the option `-protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp` and it would work fine.

So I tried this:

```
AVDictionary *d = NULL;           
av_dict_set(&d, "protocol_whitelist", "file, udp, rtp", 0); 
ret = avformat_open_input(&inFormatCtx, filename, NULL, &d);
```

But the same message still pops up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is awkward...

`avformat_open_input` failed because I have white spaces. Removing the whitespaces now work.

```
av_dict_set(&d, "protocol_whitelist", "file,udp,rtp", 0);
```

Comment: That actually didn't work for me... Is this the only change you did?

Comment: Yea. If you look at the debug, `inFormatCtx->protocol_whitelist` is set to "file,udp,rtp". Can you explain more about how it's not working for you?

Comment: I was still getting that `Protocol not on whitelist` error when I've set the protocol_whitelist in the dictionary. Might be a version issue? Anyway - It works now for both of us, so all is well :)

Comment: I am using ffmpeg-20160219-git-98a0053-win32-dev (Zeranoe builds). Did you set the AVDictionary  pointer correctly? Perhaps you could check the value after you have set it? I guess one of the challenges of FFmpeg is that there's no official guide to these things...

Comment: Great. Hopefully it will stay that way for the subsequent versions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This answer works up to some version. You should use the options parameter of avformat_open_input as described in bot1131357's answer

---

I'm not totally sure about this, but I believe this options go into the AVFormatContext

```
AVFormatContext* formatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
formatContext->protocol_whitelist = "file,udp,rtp";
if (avformat_open_input(&formatContext, uri.c_str(), NULL, NULL) != 0) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Take a look at the cvs log of this change:
https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-cvslog/2016-March/098694.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your method worked too. However the source code has this to say about protocol_whitelist: *set by user through AVOptions (**NO direct access**)* so I decided to use the Dictionary approach for now.