# Segmentation fault receiving rtp stream using FFmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtp

I would need some help with a project I am working on. Currently, I am trying to implement a program that is supposed to receiving a video stream via RTP protocol but I can't seem to figure out a solution as to why it is not working.

My program so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

#define HOST "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT "20000"
#define NETWORK_ADDRESS "rtp://@"HOST":"PORT

int main()
{
    /** Register all muxers, demuxers and üprotocolls*/
    av_register_all();
    /** Global initialization of network protocolls */
    avformat_network_init();

    /** Open video file incoming from newtwork */
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtxt = NULL;
    av_dict_set(&pFormatCtxt, "protocol_whitelist", "rtp", 0);
    if ( avformat_open_input( &pFormatCtxt, "stream.sdp", NULL, NULL ) != 0 )
        return -1;

    printf("Video file opened.\n");

    /** Retrieve stream information */
    if( avformat_find_stream_info( pFormatCtxt, NULL ) < 0 )
    return -1;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The .sdp file has been generated with the terminal command:

```
 ffmpeg -re -i GoP2_output_10fps.avi -vn -ac 1 -c:a copy -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:20000 > stream.sdp
```

According to these instructions [here](http://lucabe72.blogspot.de/2010/04/rtp-streaming-with-ffmpeg.html) I get the following content:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 57.83.100
m=video 20000 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:2418
a=rtpmap:96 MP4V-ES/90000
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=1;    config=000001B001000001B58913000001000000012000C48D8800553284A01443000001B24C61766335362E36302E313030
```

To white list the RTP protocol I used `av_dict_set(&pFormatCtxt, "protocol_whitelist", "rtp", 0)` from this SO discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380730/ffmpeg-protocol-not-on-whitelist-file).

Now after white listing it, the program execution stops after the  `avformat_open_input()` function call and outputs a segmentation fault. 
I understand this error means I am trying to access memory that I am not supposed to, but I don't understand why this is happening and how to proceed from here.

As I am quite new to the topic of ffmpeg and haven't been able to find a solution myself, I was hoping somebody here who knows their way around could provide me some help?

My OS is: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Note that in the linked question the type of the first parameter to `av_dict_set()` is `AVDictionary`, perhaps that's where undefined behavior already occurred and it's where the actual problem is. In fact, from the function name one should not attempt to pass anything that is not a dictionary.

Comment: That should be obvious from compiling with warnings. Does your code emit any warnings when compiled?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Yes, thank you very much. I completely overlooked this part. 

regarding UlrichEckhardt question, kind of stupid but I had the -w flag set when using gcc so the warnings were suppressed....

Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Inkognito try to always ensure warnings are enabled, and try to be strict too `-pedantic` if it doesn't hurt much.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @IharobAlAsimi, both of you are right of course.